How to add all object files of one single directory on the linker script?
One of the software modules of my embedded C project has a varying number of source files for each release of this module.
Note: This happens because they are being auto generated by a codegen tool.
So each time I have to build my project, the CMake build script fetches and compiles this separate source files, leaving the object files in a separate folder just for specific this software module.
After that, the linker script looks for these files one-by-one using their name. But that is not very scalable. I'd like to instruct the linker script to add all object files inside one particular folder to a given memory region.
Here's what I already tried and did not work:
*path/to/my/directory/*.c.obj(.bss)
path/to/my/directory/*.c.obj(.bss)
*path/*.c.obj(.bss)
path/*.c.obj(.bss)

Here's what currently works:
*my_file_name.c.obj(.bss)  /* Without any path and directory definition */

All my object files can be located inside one top-level build folder on my project structure.

What's the harm of including files in the project/build that contain functions which aren't called by the program? The linker won't include those in the binary executable. You get an itty bit longer compile/build-time when building everything from scratch, that's all.

I suggest to [edit] the question and show a minimal working CMake build script that demonstrates how you compile the files. Maybe this build script can be extended to generate the relevant piece of the linker script.

@Lundin All the object files I am trying to wildcard are used in the build. I am just looking for a way to programmatically add all of them to a specific memory region. I don't care much about build time here.

Why would you care exactly by file name? Just using (.bss) would add from all file no matter which is compiled in. Unless you want to split the data from the generated code into a different output section compared to the elements from non-generated code.

@Bodo unfortunately I cannot share that

@kesselhaus parts of my code will be executed using a cached RAM area and other parts will not. That's why I bother separating the memory regions

@daiogo, how does your linker command line look like? Wildcards only match files which are explicitly specified on the command line. The linker does not search directories to expand wildcards.

Something like this might work:

Create a custom section in the linker script. Lets say it is called "my_memory".

In the place where your compiler would expect you to add non-standard C stuff to place a function or variable in a custom section, write a macro.
For example if the compiler expects this:
int x __attribute__((section("my_memory"))) = 123;

Then rewrite it with a macro like:
int x MY_MEMORY = 123;


In some global header my_memory.h, define this macro as empty:
#define MY_MEMORY


Now your code as-is will compile cleanly still no matter what, because the macro is a no-op.

Write a script that you launch from the programming IDE before compiling. (Could be written in C or some other language.) In this script, parse my_memory.h or replace it entirely so that you get:
#define MY_MEMORY __attribute__((section("name")))


Or you could replace the header file with version control/build settings. Or you could perhaps cheekily place one my_memory.h in every directory of the project, as long as you know that the linker will pick the one in same directory as the source file you are building.



That's a great solution! Unfortunately it won't work on my case because this code that I'm trying to link is implemented by a code generation tool. Hence, we cannot manually change it to add the attributes.
